# What is the purpose of Escape Sequence \' in java?

Tags: java, escaping

if I print ' (single quote) in the `System.out.println()` I can get exact output.

Like :

```
System.out.println("test'test");
output:  test'test
```

What is the purpose of using \' escape sequence in java?

This also gives me the same output.

```
 System.out.println("test\'test");
 output:  test'test
```

pls explain what is the main purpose of \' escape sequence in java

Answer (score 11):

It's for use in character literals:

```
char c = '\'';
```

Without that, it would be painful to get a single apostrophe as a `char`.

Comment: I got it..thank you for your short and precise answer

Answer (score 4):

This is useful for character literals stored in `char`.

Imagine you want a character constant to just hold a `'`. You could do:

```
public static final char SINGLE_QUOTE = '';
```

This won't work as it only is an empty character, but we want a single quote. Hence the escape character `\'`.

```
public static final char SINGLE_QUOTE = '\'';
```

If you print it on `System.out.println`, you'll see the difference.

For an exercise, try and take your **exact** example and see if you can print a double quote literal `"` without escaping it. You'll see it's not possible. You will have to escape it with `\"`.

Reference: [String literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) and [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).